# How to select row in Grid on right click and show context menu simultaniously?

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Using Vaadin 24:

I tried to use GridContextMenu `grid.addContextMenu()`, which opens with right click, however it does not select row on which I clicked and I can't find such option on GridContextMenu instance to set.

Secondly, I tried to add click listener and check mouse button, however I do not know how to get the row index I clicked:

```
grid.addItemClickListener(event -> {
    val column = event.getColumn(); // can get only column
    val buttonCode = event.getButton();
    if (buttonCode == 2) { // 2 is secondary button / right button
        // select here
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that Grid columns are sortable - `setSortable(true)` and reordable - `setColumnReorderingAllowed(true)`. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use addGridContextMenuOpenedListener from GridContextMenu.

```java
final var menu = grid.addContextMenu();
menu.addGridContextMenuOpenedListener(event -> event.getItem().ifPresent(grid::select));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a GridContextMenu you can register a listener:

```
addGridContextMenuOpenedListener( new ComponentEventListener<GridContextMenu.GridContextMenuOpenedEvent<Object>>(){
    @Override
    public void onComponentEvent(GridContextMenuOpenedEvent<Object> event) {
        if (event.getItem().isPresent()) {
            Grid<Object> grid = ((Grid<Object>) getTarget());
            grid.select( event.getItem().get() );
        }
    }
} );
```